# Pytorch backpropagation

Tags: pytorch

When there are max and absolute value operations in the pytorch model, how does pytorch implement the gradient descent of these operations during backpropagation
please give a detail answer,thank you!

Comment: `torch.abs` is non-differentiable only at 0, and it seems that pytorch implements a 0 derivative over some interval [-epsilon,+epsilon] near 0 https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-autograd-deal-with-non-differentiable-opponents-such-as-abs-and-max/34538. `torch.max` is just an index selection operation, which has gradient of 1 for the selected indices and 0 for the non-selected indices. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11699/backprop-through-max-pooling-layers

Answer (score 0):

`torch.abs` is non-differentiable only at 0, and it seems that pytorch implements a 0 derivative over some interval [-epsilon,+epsilon] near 0 https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-autograd-deal-with-non-differentiable-opponents-such-as-abs-and-max/34538. `torch.max` is just an index selection operation, which has gradient of 1 for the selected indices and 0 for the non-selected indices. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11699/backprop-through-max-pooling-layers